# Will there be a performance gain by using Apache's mod_proxy to proxy off static file requests to Lighttpd/nginx?

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, lighttpd, mod-proxy

I know there are lot of tutorials out there which suggest the use either nginx or lighttpd on port 80 and proxy dynamic requests to apache running on a different port. I am not ready to take that leap yet for my VPS. However I could definitely try the reverse scenario.

i.e. use apache's mod_proxy to proxy requests to nginx/lighttpd running on a different port.

But does that even make sense? will there be a performance gain if I use the reverse setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The performance on that is pretty much guaranteed to be significantly worse than just serving the static content out of Apache.

Furthermore, I don't think the performance gains to be had (if any) from serving static content from nginx outweigh the downsides of proxying dynamic requests back to Apache -- that is to say, the "conventional wisdom" embodied in the "lot of tutorials" is just plain wrong, stupid, and generally unnecessary (who would have thought it -- bad information on the Internet?).  I'd be willing to wear the idea of using nginx to serve static assets from a separate assets domain, on a separate IP (even if it's on the same box), but I don't think proxying webserver to webserver makes sense.

Comment: Eek, I might have had the right initial impulse, to call this one subjective.  For what it's worth, I completely agree that using a "lighter" web server as a reverse proxy at all times as standard practice should be burned from our collective "conventional wisdom", and that there's very rarely an excuse for it from a performance perspective.  I just felt the need to give my answer a qualifier in the form of "but, in this insane edge-case, it could make sense."

Comment: Substitute "subjective" for "busted".  Preference given to demonstrations where something gets blown up.

Comment: I can get behind that.

Comment: I agree, putting nginx on the front proxying back to Apache makes no sense. I will however point out that nginx performs quite better on the same hardware and it scales higher COMPARED to Apache :-)

Comment: Well, someone put a down-vote on both answers, so I guess we've got some proponents of the single-node reverse proxy architecture around here somewhere.  @pauska There's that subjectivity again ;).

Comment: No, that is not subjectivity at all. Do your homework :-) nginx (stripped down to the bare necessary modules) scales higher on the same hardware.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very uncommon setup, I've never heard about anyone using nginx/lighttpd as a backend. It doesn't make sense, as you want the front-end to be the absolutely fastest point for serving static files (nginx, lighttpd) or caching both static and dynamic (varnish etc).

If you're really bound to use Apache as a front-end then just keep it.

Comment: Its not that uncommon, if you search for it on google, various blog posts claiming its performance benifits, but didn't make sense to me, thats why the query

Comment: Yes, you'll get results from google, same as you would if you search for "how to eat poop".. I think you get my point :)